# how to extract attachements from Outlook emails 2010 using Java?

Tags: java, email, pdf, outlook, attachment

I am new to Java and I would like to know if is possible to extract attachements from emails  in Outlook 2010  using Java? Such as copying the attachments into a folder for example.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4780870/ideas-about-linux-based-solutions-for-parsing-email-storage-files-of-ms-outlook

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a package from Moyosoft that can help you achieve this. Of course, this comes with a price, but it fits the description of your question perfectly.

I do not know of any open source package that does this.

If you do not want to pay for it, why not just connect to the email server and retrieve it that way instead?

[Java Outlook Connector - Moyosoft](http://www.moyosoft.com/joc/)